# Fill a numpy matrix's certain column with 1 if all columns are 0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Let's say I have this matrix :

```
> mat
  index   values
    0   0 0 0 0 0
    1   0 0 0 0 0
    2   0 1 0 0 0
    3   0 1 0 0 0
    4   0 0 0 0 0
    5   0 0 0 0 0
    6   0 0 1 0 0
    7   0 0 1 0 0
    8   0 0 0 0 0
```

I want to fill mat's first column with the value 1 if all the columns in the iterated row are 0.

So that mat will look like this :

```
> mat
  index   values
    0   1 0 0 0 0
    1   1 0 0 0 0
    2   0 1 0 0 0
    3   0 1 0 0 0
    4   1 0 0 0 0
    5   1 0 0 0 0
    6   0 0 1 0 0
    7   0 0 1 0 0
    8   1 0 0 0 0
```

Here's what I have tried :

```
for i in range(len(mat)):
   for j in range(5):
       if (mat[i][j]!=1):
           mat[i][0]=1
```

But this puts 1 in all columns. Why ?

Comment: just take the sum of the entire row, if the sum > 0, change the 0th column of the row as 1, else leave it as it is. Try it yourself.

Comment: Okay, Thank you.

Comment: When you say “numpy matrix”, do you mean a matrix object or just a 2D ndarray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(mat)):
  for j in range(5):
      if (mat[i][j]!=1):
          mat[i][0]=1
```

This doesn't work because it would set the first column to 1 if any column has a zero. You want to set first column to 1 if all columns have a 0

This would work

```
for i in range(len(mat)):
  for j in range(5):
      if (mat[i][j]==1):
          break;
      mat[i][0] = 1
```

Also, a much better solution would be to use sum

```
for i in range(len(mat)):
  if (sum(mat[i]) == 0):
     mat[i][0] = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution is to evaluate the row with [`numpy.any()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.any.html):

```py
for i in range(len(mat)):
   mat[i][0] = 0 if np.any(mat[i]) else 1
```

or simply without a for-loop

```py
mat[:,0] = ~np.any(mat, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mat[mat.sum(axis=1).astype(np.bool).flat] = 1
```